Is it possible to use MockRestServiceServer for HTTP Interface Client?
I'm trying to introduce HTTP Interface Client that is available from Spring Framework 6 to my project but it seems difficult to bind implementation classes that are generated from HTTP Interfaces to MockRestServiceServer.
I know it's possible if the RestClient instance and its builder are shared between HTTP Interface Client generations but I want to have their own RestClient instances cause each of them should have its own base URL and default headers.
Any ideas?
